# Change select list to radio buttons.

Tags: theming, forms, users

I want to modify my register page and add some fields from 'profile' content, for example: gender.

So Ive got:

function mysite_preprocess_user_register(&$variables) {
   unset ($variables['form']['Personal Information']['profile_gender']['#description'] );
   .... 
}

In this point when i print_r profile_gender Ive got:

```
Array ( [#type] => select [#title] => Gender [#default_value] => [#options] => Array ( [0] => -- [Select] => Select [Male] => Male [Female] => Female ) [#required] => 0 [#post] => Array ( ) [#programmed] => [#tree] => [#parents] => Array ( [0] => profile_gender ) [#array_parents] => Array ( [0] => Personal Information [1] => profile_gender ) [#weight] => 0.003 [#processed] => 1 [#attributes] => Array ( ) [#input] => 1 [#size] => 0 [#multiple] => [#process] => Array ( [0] => form_expand_ahah ) [#name] => profile_gender [#id] => edit-profile-gender [#value] => [#defaults_loaded] => 1 [#sorted] => 1 )
```

And when I want to change #type to **'radios'** displays me nothing..

Like:

```
  $variables['form']['Personal Information']['profile_gender']['#type'] = 'radios';
  $variables['form']['Personal Information']['profile_gender']['#options'] = array('0'=>t('Male'),'1'=>t('Female'));
  $variables['form']['Personal Information']['profile_gender']['#default_value'] = 'Male';

    $variables['gender'] = drupal_render($variables['form']['Personal Information']['profile_gender']);
```

Any ideas how to change that from select list to radios(male/female)?

Comment: Profile lets you display its fields on the register page. Why not using this ?

Answer (score 2):

The preprocess functions are about rendering the output. Removing and adding form element with FAPI must be done earlier.

You have to do this with [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7). It's also very likely that you have to *add* a custom submission handler to process and save the user input. You can hook in your handler in hook_form_alter as well.

Comment: and how can I use it for edit this field? Any example?

Comment: If anyone is intrested (I cant reply my own post):

    function my_site_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id)
    {
     // add radios
       if ($form_id == 'user_register') {
    
        $form['Personal Information']['profile_gender']['#type'] = 'radios';
        $form['Personal Information']['profile_gender']['#options'] = array('0'=>t('Male'),'1'=>t('Female'));
        $form['Personal Information']['profile_gender']['#default_value'] = 'Male';
     }
     }